# Is this writing correct?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

A book which I study to learn assembly language had defined the below example to change the # symbol to $ symbol. However, when I try this in emu8086, it doesn't work.

When I click the emulate this code it shows me an error like (18) wrong parameters LEA [DI], DIZI

What is the problem?

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 64

    .DATA
    DIZI DB 'LDA#305A'

    .CODE
    ANA PROC FAR
        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV DS, AX
        CLD
        MOV AL, '#'
        MOV BH, '$'
        MOV CX, 9
        LEA DS:DI, DIZI
        REPNE SCASB
        JNE CIK
        MOV BYTE PTR[DI-1], BH   

  CIK:  MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H        

   ANA  ENDP
        END ANA
```

Comment: Please expand on "it doesn't work".

Comment: Remove the "DS:", leave only the DI.

Comment: @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez It still shows # symbol in string in that way.

Comment: so what is in your source. "LEA [DI],DIZI" or "LEA DS:DI, DIZI"? And what is in the book? The correct Intel syntax is `lea di,[DIZI]`, segment prefix `ds:` is not needed, as `lea` does not access memory for real, it just calculates address. emu8086 does support also MASM/TASM syntax where the square brackets are in this particular case not required, but rather stick to official Intel syntax when possible, makes it easier to read the source.  ... About code not replacing # .. update the listing + check in debugger by stepping, what happens.

Comment: I'm not even sure where do you expect the change to "show". Do you have memory view open in debugger, pointed at `DIZI` address? The code is just overwriting byte in memory. It doesn't "display" it anywhere. So if you put breakpoint at `CIK:`, and run to it, the memory at address `DIZI` should contain modified values.

Comment: And that code is invalid, `scasb` works over `es` segment register, and can NOT be overridden, but you don't set `es`, only `ds`. Check the book one more time, make sure you have every single character correctly, then either you did read it wrong, or get other book.

Comment: @Ped7g The book wants to change # symbol and write instead of that $ symbol. (So, at same address in DIZI). I tried what you said but couldn't change DIZI. It would be better if you write exact answer as in this description.

Comment: @Ped7g Ouch. Most books contain typos; perhaps first check if the author's page has errata.

Comment: I don't have emu8086 to verify my SYNTAX (I can verify only with NASM in 32b or 64b environment). And I wonder why you are learning an obsolete technology, which is actually on many levels more complex than 32b protected mode with flat memory mapping. If you want something simple, I have seen recently javascript 8 bit assembler simulator, there's no book or tutorial on it, but if you would try to apply 8086 books crossed with Z80 books, it would maybe work for you. The bonus is, that that machine is SUPER simple, can't be simpler.

Comment: @Ped7g The book had mentioned the change DS to ES is a necessary but it hadn't implemented what it said and unfortunately I don't know how I can implement that.

Comment: @NoWeDoR so.. compare my result with original and try to understand what I did change... re-read also previous chapters quickly to see of some confusing paragraphs will suddenly make more sense. Segment registers are a bit special, so maybe you didn't get the details first time reading about them. Keep returning to basics after every few examples, as it's almost 100% sure you misunderstood some things. Keep stepping over single instruction in debugger and watching registers and memory values, trying to understand why and how. ASM is actually super simple when single instruction is involved.

Comment: can you maybe add name of book and example number/chapter/page (in the title of question probably), so in case somebody else will be looking for this particular one, he will have chance to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blind try to fix the code for emu8086:

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 64

    .DATA
    DIZI DB 'LDA#305A'

    .CODE
    ANA PROC FAR
        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV ES, AX    ; es for SCASB
        CLD
        MOV AL, '#'
        MOV BH, '$'
        MOV CX, 9
        LEA DI, [DIZI]
        REPNE SCASB         ; should now work over correct ES:DI memory.
        JNE CIK
        MOV [ES:DI-1], BH   ; try ES:[DI-1] in case of syntax err.
        ; ^^ needs now "ES:" prefix, because I don't set "DS"

  CIK:  MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H        

   ANA  ENDP
        END ANA
```

---

Another option is to set both `ds` and `es`, like this:

```
    ANA PROC FAR
        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV DS, AX    ; ds for default memory access
        MOV ES, AX    ; es for SCASB
...
... then modifying the char can be done without "ES:" prefix, using default "DS:"
        JNE CIK
        MOV [DI-1], BH
...
```

---

Also it's important to read detailed description of instructions you use. For example the SCASB is quite special, it is fixed to `ES:DI` memory pointer, and can't be overridden by any segment prefix (contrary to 80% other instructions, which can be prefixed from default DS/SS to any other).

The "string" intruction family (where SCASB belongs) is particularly tricky, because the source pointer DS:SI can be overridden, thus:

```
    MOVSB  ; moves single byte from [DS:SI] to [ES:DI], ++SI, ++DI

    SS:MOVSB ; moves single byte [SS:SI] to [ES:DI], ++SI, ++DI
```

Usually the easiest way to verify any instruction against your assumptions is to enter into google "`x86 <name_of_instruction>`" and look for some domain name you will recognize over time to contain the original Intel docs converted into HTML. Like for example this one: http://x86.renejeschke.de/

Comment: I hadn't paid attention your comment line. It must have ES:[DI-1]. Thanks!

Comment: @NoWeDoR  I'm now used to NASM syntax, where segment prefix goes inside `[]`. Once you will get a bit more comfortable with what instructions can do and how they *may* look, you will start to ignore these tiny syntax differences, and you will be able to correctly fix them on the fly, when somebody will advice you by accident in syntax of other assembler. (the machine code produced is of course the same one, so if you will disassemble it by debugger, you will get one more different syntax, this time the one used by disassembler)

Comment: "...moves single byte from [DS:SI] to [ES:DI], ++SI, ++DI..." Ordinarily these notations mean *pre-increment*, but all string primitives only allow *post-increment* and *post-decrement*

Comment: @SepRoland in C/C++ expression is evaluated left to right, so first the part "copy" is evaluated, then increments. If I would write "moves single byte from [DS:++SI] to [ES:++DI]", then it would be clearly incorrect. I admit my triple-part-expression may be somewhat confusing to people who are used to increment value by 1 by the post-increment notation even when not interested into original value, like `for ( ; ; i++ )` instead of semantically more accurate `for ( ; ; ++i)`.